# Using php variable from one isset to another

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a page where on form submit from previous page a div with something like invoice is created. I send that data to server and populate the invoice for print/generate PDF etc.

```
if (isset($_POST['kreiraj'])) {
    $emailuser = $_POST["na_email"];   
}
```

On same page I create with JS a PDF from canvas of that invoice and send it via Ajax for posting into PHP mail script witch is also on same page.

```
if (isset($_POST['fileDataURI'])) {
    $pdfdoc         = $_POST['fileDataURI'];
 };
```

This all works but I have problems accessing PHP variables from each other. 
I have read about function global and $_GLOBLAS[varables] but nothing seems to work for me. Can someone point out a way to do it? 
TO be exact  i need to access $emailuser from example code above in if `(isset($_POST['fileDataURI']))` php mailing script.

Comment: From what you wrote, it seems that one of these bits of code is run when you submit a form and the other is run through Ajax? If so, those are two separate requests, as far as the server is concerned. The `$_GLOBALS` variable (which you should try to avoid whenever possible!) does not persist from request to another. To do that, you typically want to use a session.

Comment: @GregSchmidt That worked! Thanks a lot! Feel free to post it as answer.